# Slider only slide once - WHY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, jquery-slider

I have added a slider to my site but it seems to only run once. It stops on 2nd image.
I want it to keep sliding every 5 seconds. Please help me!

Source: http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl

Javascript:

```
var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};


$('a.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('a.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});

$(function(){
setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Include The code just after $(document).ready()  =>  
setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();    }, 3000);

Comment: Ignore  last Dash (-) , Stackoverflow automatically included it.

Comment: Keep in mind i adjusted to make the code autoplay without a checkbox.

Comment: Hey Patrik, tried that but it doesn't work. Very wierd. Looks like this now in top: jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

 setInterval(function () { moveRight(); }, 3000);

Answer (score 0):

find and update your code with:

remove checkbox function "$('#checkbox').change(function() ... " or just replace with

```
setInterval(function () {
      moveRight();
  }, 5000);
```

that'll fix it.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/kzkpro/pen/aHALy)

[Demo](http://codepen.io/kzkpro/full/aHALy)

Comment: But then it doesn't slide automaticly. I need it to slide automaticly every 5 seconds. How can i do that?

Comment: what do you mean "it doesn't slide automaticly"? did you mean auto sliding without clicking checkbox?

Comment: currently auto slide works fine when you click checkbox. http://codepen.io/kzkpro/full/aHALy

Comment: I mean that i want to remove the checkbox. It should slide automaticly without any checkbox.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I really don't understand why. It only slides one time. Then it stops. I can still use the buttons right and left to slide tho.

Comment: weird! which browser are you using? it works fine with chrome(slides in every five seconds).

Comment: also working fine in firefox and IE 11. may be something wrong with your system!!!